# How much of the game is playble for free?

Tags: card-hunter

I've gotten through several quests now, and am up to around level 7 both in terms of characters' levels and renown. Now, I've turned up a couple of quests that appear locked.

These being my first locked levels, the game appears to be granting me some gratuitous in-game currency (pizza) to purchase one. However, it seems this currency normally requires real-world money to purchase.

Am I going to eventually reach a point where a substantial amount of content is locked behind a paywall? Or are there in-game methods of earning your way towards purchasing the content without spending real money? If there is no in-game mechanism for earning the purchasable content, how much of the game's content will I be able to play for free?

Answer (score 1):

I've played quite a bit of this game, and have found that a good bit of it is locked. However these are just the optional quests, you can still progress through the game without them. You can do all of the story for free.