# When do I get to sell usable items?

Tags: card-hunter

I'm at renown level 7 now, and I've accrued quite the stock of armor, weapons, and other usable items. However, up until this point, I have not been allowed to sell them.

Every time I try, the game says I will be able to do this later in the campaign. When will that happen? Will I get there before hitting a [paywall](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/252623/how-much-of-the-game-is-playble-for-free)?

Comment: Turns out the trigger happened just last night, in the middle of a quest. (Didn't make note of which one, unfortunately.) I'm not sure exactly what the trigger is, as it happened at kind-of an odd point - right after one of the encounters of the quest, but not the last one, at the loot screen. FWIW: I've played pretty much straight through the campaign, and only the campaign, so far. I've maybe repeated just one or two quests along the way, and finished last night around character level 9 and renown 8.

Answer (score 1):

> **After opening your first chest after reaching renown 7.**

Source: [New Player FAQ](https://forums.cardhunter.com/threads/new-player-faq.7451/#post-91623). DunDunDun @ Card Hunter Forum. Jul 13, 2015.

Answer (score 0):

You can't sell until level 7 (can't remember if that's adventure, or character level), it's a safeguard to prevent new players from selling things they will later wish that they had. Just FYI, you'll need some of those "junk" items later when you unlock quests